# How to select elements from autosuggest box using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

I m sending the firepath screenshot

[image]

I want to select first element and display in element text box

Can someone please help in this

Comment: is that auto suggest dropdown fields will display on entering text in input field box?

Answer (score -1):

You can update your code as below:

```
public class SelectAutoSugggestedValue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys("automation tutorial");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        List allOptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td/span[text()='automationtutorial']"));

        for (int i = 0; i < allOptions.size(); i++) {
            String option = allOptions.get(i).getText();
            System.out.println(option);
        }
    }
}
```